# upload .csv file and count of rows should reflect based on inputfile in valuebox() in shinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to upload **data.csv** file into shinyApp and use that file data to *calculate* some figures and again that figure need to reflect in **valueBox()**.

[image]

```
data.csv : 
col1   col2,
1       10,
2       20,
3       30,
```

I want to display sum(col2) value in valueBox() automatically after uploaded the data.csv file.

```
box(div(h4("UPTIME:", align = "center")), 
    column(4, fileInput(inputId = "in", label = "import", accept = 
    ".csv")),
    column(8, valueBox("scr1", sum(data$col2), width = 12)), width = 12)
```

I could able to upload the data.csv file. But can't stored data.csv in variable called 'data' as dataframe and calculate the sum of col2 to diplay as sum(data$col2) into valueBox().

Example of outcome should be like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working app below.

Couple of remarks:

- It seems like you currently define everything in your UI. You can't access the `data` object in that scope. Since your `valueBox` should display dynamic data (based on the file you upload you should use a `valueBoxOutput` and `renderValueBox` function. Check the documentation for `valueBox` [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#valuebox).
- Since we don't know the column name of the csv-file the user uploads, it is better to target it like `data[,2]` instead of `data$col2` since this would require every uploaded csv to have a `col2` name in the header.
- I changed the inputId for `fileInput` from `in` to `file` since `in` is a reserved word in R.
- Your example also does not show any input file handling. Take a look at the `fileInput` documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html) to see a minimal example.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Upload Stats"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        box(
            title = "UPTIME:",
            width = 12,
            div(
                column(
                    width = 4, 
                    fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "import", accept = ".csv")
                ),
                column(
                    width = 8, 
                    valueBoxOutput("stats")
                )
            )
        ) 
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$stats <- renderValueBox({
        req(input$file)
        data <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)
        valueBox("scr1", sum(data[,2]), width = 12)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Everytime I run the app it asks me to upload file. I want it to upload once in a day and it will get freezed. Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: After uploaded the **data.csv**, the 'import' button should not be there for the day. Again on next day (means after 23:59:59 hrs) it will active to accept the upload of **data.csv** again. So this should happen daily basis. Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be best to ask this as a new question!